# Tensorflow: how to get the current variable scope as a python string (hopefully without creating a variable)

Tags: tensorflow

It is not mentioned in the documentation:
https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope

Does anyone know how?
Thanks!

Comment: I just figured out one way: if we create the scope with "with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:" then we can get the scope as string by doing "scope.name"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out the current variable_scope and you are operating in tensorflow r 1.1.0:

```
print(tf.get_variable_scope().name)
```